# Using SafeCracker in ExpressionEngine Strips HTML and CSS Inline Styles

Tags: php, forms, expressionengine, safecracker

I have a form built with SafeCracker in ExpressionEngine. One of the textarea fields is used to allow users to submit HTML code.

Here's an example of the type of code they will be providing:

`<div style="left: 385px; top: 137px;" class="aaa"></div>`.

When the form is submitted and the entry is saved to the database, SafeCracker strips out the inline CSS style. The result of what is actually saved to the database is:

`<div class="aaa"></div>`.

As you can see, the inline CSS style(s) are being removed but the rest of the HTML is maintained.

I want to allow users to be able to submit HTML code and not have SafeCracker strip out the inline CSS style(s). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SafeCracker uses the built-in ExpressionEngine [XSS Sanitization Method](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/guidelines/security.html#cross_site_scripting_xss) to clean user submitted input from Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Any front-side user input is sanitized by using `$this->EE->security->xss_clean()` before being inserted into the database or output to the screen.

Thankfully for us, the Engineers at EllisLab have provided a secret, undocumented way of "whitelisting" **fieldtypes** and **field_ids** used in SafeCracker and exempting them from XSS filtering.

To stop [SafeCracker](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/safecracker/) from stripping all HTML from a given field, open up the following file, depending on which version of ExpressionEngine you're running:

> **EE 2.1.3 or Earlier** (SafeCracker installed as Third-Party Add-On)
>   `/system/expressionengine/third_party/safecracker/libraries/safecracker_lib.php`

---

> **EE 2.2.0 or Later** (SafeCracker installed as First-Party Module)
>   `/system/expressionengine/modules/safecracker/libraries/safecracker_lib.php`

*Note: ExpressionEngine 2.2.0 bundles SafeCracker as a first-party module, so your installation location will depend on what version you're running or have upgraded from.*

Scroll down to around **Line 2371 (for EE 2.1.3)** or **Line 2516 (for EE 2.2)** and look for the following:

```
$this->skip_xss_fieldtypes = array();
$this->skip_xss_field_ids = array();
```

Here's where the fun begins. To "whitelist" a field from having the XSS Filter applied, simply add the **fieldtype** or **field_id** to either array.

Here's an example:

```
$this->skip_xss_fieldtypes = array(
    // This is the fieldtype as specified in the Control Panel
    // Channel Fields, not what you use in your SafeCracker template
    'textarea'
);
$this->skip_xss_field_ids = array(
    // This is the field_id from the exp_channel_data MySQL Table
    'field_id_1'
);
```

You can either specify a certain type of **fieldtype** (textarea, input, etc.), or the **field_id** if you'd rather be more explicit. The former way is more general, while the latter is absolute and is more flexible if a custom field would to ever change its type.

With these changes, any field(s) you exempt from the XSS Sanitization Method will no longer have any filtering applied, and allow any arbitrary HTML to be submitted into the database!

*Keep in mind, that any upgrades to ExpressionEngine may overwrite this file, so you may want to change the permissions on the file or keep a backup handy.*

Cross Site Scripting should be taken very seriously as you would never want your site to be the source of an attack vector. Always err on the side of caution.

Comment: @rjb Thanks for the detailed explanation. But how come this only happens in EE2.2 and not EE2.0. I never had issue with inline styling being striped out in EE2.0. That's only the case in 2.2.

Comment: The built-in XSS sanitization method is constantly being tweaked for improved security and performance, so it may have changed between versions. You might also want to check your [Channel Posting Preferences](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/content_admin/channel_edit_preferences.html) and verify you have **Allow ALL HTML** for the setting **Default HTML Formatting in Channel Entries**.

Comment: Yes i already have Allow ALL HTML. Are you able to find out if there was in fact any different in XSS sanitization between the 2 versions.

Comment: Also how would inline styling pose any xss risks.

Comment: I compared both 2.0 and 2.2 safecracker folders, and non show that style property would be striped out. This doesn't appear to be a safecracker issue. I wonder what other files to look into that could affect this. Everything works find if i post an entry in CP. This only appears to be an issue with safecracker form in EE2.2 where it strips out inline styling.

Comment: ExpressionEngine's XSS sanitization method is part of the CodeIgniter framework. The code itself is spread out amongst many different files and is thousands of lines long – it's futile to try comparing. If you were truly running EE 2.0 (the Public Beta) and just upgraded to EE 2.2, there have been *a lot* of changes, so I wouldn't worry about trying to understand why; instead, embrace what is possible and works in the present ... not debug how something worked in the past :)

Comment: Yes you are right. But the solution you provided will make the skipped field vulnerable to xss attacks. All i want to do is allow inline styling, an no JavaScript.

Comment: May I suggest you post in the official EE support forums, since SC is now a first-party module?

Comment: @d-rock, I did post on EE form and they confirmed as @rjb suggested, that inline styling are being stripped out to sanitize the input. I will try rjb's workaround after i heard back EE regarding further details about this issue. Thanks